# Recurly Account Subscription

Tags: python, recurly

I'm trying through Python to get a Recurly account email given a subscription or a subscription state given an account email. When I try drilling from account into subscription for example, I get a

```
for account in r.Account.all():
    print 'Account: %s' % account
    print 'Sub: %s' % account.subscriptions
```

When I try to access account.subscription.state I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'state'
```

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `account` has many `subscriptions`, so you'll need to iterate through each subscription and print its state. The following should work for ya:

```
    for account in recurly.Account.all():
       print 'Account: %s' % account
       for subscription in account.subscriptions():
          print 'Subscription: %s' % subscription.state
```